# Which MobileDB Container to prefer for storing a user data model(iOS)?

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

I want to make an app where I fetch data from an api service as json. The data is a simple user data of a student like rollNo, name, course, semester, attendance of subjects and their marks, etc.

So my question is Which Container should I prefer, for persistence and to store my user data model, among 'UserDefaults', 'CoreData' and 'Realm'?

Answer (score 1):

If you want easy data base using then choose Realm. Also realm is faster, cause it was written on c language. But its weight is more than CoreData has.

Comment: Realm suits more for dynamic data which I do have. But I just have to store a single user's data while login and to fetch it each time user opens the app.

Comment: @MasterAgentX If your data is not big, you can store it in user defaults. If the information is private you can encrypt it by yourself